# Storing values for resuse while operating on a selection

Tags: d3.js

```
// Append circle.
foo.append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return coordinate(d, i, "x"); })
.attr("cy", function(d, i) { return coordinate(d, i, "y"); })
.attr("r", 50);

// Append text.
foo.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d, i) { return coordinate(d, i, "x"); })
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return coordinate(d, i, "y"); })
.text("bar")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + 45 + ", " + coordinate(d, i, "x") + ", " + coordinate(d, i, "y") + ")"; });

// Calculate coordinate function.
function coordinate(d, i, type) {
  ...
  // return an x or y coordinate
}
```

I have a function which calculates a coordinate. I am calling it multiple times in order to position some elements. I cannot easily contain the elements in a `<g>` and translate it. Is there a way of getting my coordinates once, putting them in a variable, and then accessing that variable every time I need it to position an element. The coordinates change in each iteration of my dataset. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to modify the data such that it includes the x and y coordinates in it.

```js
// after binding modify data
    foo.data(function(d,i) { d.x = coordinate(d, i, "x");
                            d.y = coordinate(d, i, "y");
                            return d;
                           } );

    // Append circle.
    foo.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", 50);

    // Append text.
    foo.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return d.x; })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return d.y; })
    .text("bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "rotate(" + 45 + ", " + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });

    // Calculate coordinate function.
    function coordinate(d, i, type) {
      ...
      // return an x or y coordinate
    }
```

Comment: slightly modified my answer